# Where are third party addons stored?

Tags: add-on

I installed a third party addon earlier today that I believe is causing Blender to crash whenever I open it. I found the folder where the 'built-in' addons are installed, but not the folder for third party addons (I am guessing, as that folder doesn't have any of my other third party addons). I deleted the original addon zip file from where it was installed, which did nothing. I also tried restarting my computer, which did not affect anything. Is it possible to delete an addon from a file folder, since I can't open the software? Let me know if a crash log might help, and I'll upload one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender's third-party(user installed) add-ons are stored in these locations:

**Windows:**

`%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.5\scripts\addons\`

**Linux:**

`$HOME/.config/blender/3.5/scripts/addons/`

**Mac OS:**

`/Users/$USER/Library/Application Support/Blender/3.5/scripts/addons/`

You can also see it exactly in the Preferences, Add-ons tab, if you select some user installed add-on:

[image]

Comment: I actually just found it right as you were posting your reply. Thanks a bunch. For me, it was in "AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.5\scripts\addons"

Comment: Yep, so that's the same as `%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.5\scripts\addons\` But you can copy paste that %appdata% thing into file explorers address bar, or Windows run menu(WInLogo key + R).

Comment: I don't use Linux often, but I think the path might be different in some cases. I am not sure if it's the same if you install Blender through Snap Store...

Comment: The location is usually listed under the details of the addon against the 'File:' entry under Preferences > Addons > <Addon_name> if you click the dropdown against its entry.

Comment: Sometimes add-ons offer their own settings/preferences. Where are those stored?

Comment: @ShoeOffHead Add-on developers generally should want to store them with the add-on or Blender config in the user preferences folder, because those are the expected places. It's not very smart to do otherwise with Blender releases coming out every few months. It is logical to store them in some sort of text files. But there is nothing stopping anyone from going crazy and storing the setting anywhere at all. So you should expect settings to be copied if you copy the user preferences folder, but it's technically possible to store them anywhere.